# What is the default queue size for apache tomcat in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

What is the default request queue size in apache tomcat which is embedded in spring boot ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of spring boot version 2.7.2, this is set to `100` by default. You can use the following property to change it:

```
server.tomcat.accept-count=100
```

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.7.2/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.java#L406-L410) this is used to specify:

> Maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing threads are in use.

To check for the version you're using, you can try replacing the version in [this url](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.7.2/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.java) & searching for `acceptCount`.

Answer (score -1):

The maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing threads are in use. Any requests received when the queue is full will be refused. In Spring Boot, we can define the maximum amount of Tomcat worker threads are 200. You may specify this property in your application.properties as follows.

```
server.tomcat.max-threads=200
```

Comment: i believe this configuration is for worker threads.. i'm looking for the request queue

Comment: that configuration max-threads=200 means the thread pool has 200 workers at most, can process 200 requests simultaneously.

Comment: it wouldn't help if there were 200 threads available to handle a request queue that is configured to 100 max. Though requests can be queued (and handled by fewer threads than the size of the request queue)